# In Laravel Filament Admin, how do I send data from the form to an external controller instead of the regular putting the data in the db

Tags: laravel-9, laravel-filament, filamentphp

By Default the resource display the data in the table and the form just add more record but i want to use the form to query the database and return result. I know I have to connect it to a controller but don't know how

```
public static function form(Form $form): Form
    {
        return $form
            ->schema([
                DatePicker::make('transaction_date')->label('Start Date')->columnSpanFull(),
                DatePicker::make('transaction_date')->label('End Date')->columnSpanFull(),
                Select::make('report_type')
                    ->label('Select Report Type')
                    ->columnSpanFull()
                    ->options([
                        'total_fee' => 'Total Fee',
                        'total_amount' => 'Total Amount',
                    ]),
            ]);
    }
```